# NiFi instance in docker container has buttons grayed out

Tags: docker, apache-nifi

I have set up NiFi on a virtual machine using a docker container. My NiFi instance is secured. The container is running fine and I am able to open the NiFi UI as well, but all the buttons on the UI are grayed out. Like the current user does not have the necessary access. Although I am logged in as an admin user. I used the following command to bring up the docker container.

```
sudo docker run --name nifi-ssl \
  -v /home/azureuser/docker_nifi/nifi_stores:/opt/certs \
  -p 8443:8443 \
  -e NIFI_WEB_PROXY_HOST="some dns":8443 \
  -e AUTH=tls \
  -e KEYSTORE_PATH=/opt/certs/keystore.jks \
  -e KEYSTORE_TYPE=JKS \
  -e KEYSTORE_PASSWORD="somevalue"  \
  -e TRUSTSTORE_PATH=/opt/certs/truststore.jks \
  -e TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD="somevalue" \
  -e TRUSTSTORE_TYPE=JKS \
  -e INITIAL_ADMIN_IDENTITY='CN=sys_admin, OU=NIFI' \
  -d \
  apache/nifi:latest
```

I am loggin in with the ceritificate of CN=sys_admin, OU=NIFI still all the buttons are secured. I am unable to find out what the problem is. This linke [here](http://apache-nifi-users-list.2361937.n4.nabble.com/Buttons-are-greyed-out-when-initial-admin-account-logs-in-td3603.html) suggests to delete the users.xml and authorizations.xml and restart NiFi. But this is not possible with the contianer, as I am unabel to delete the files and restart the nifi running inside the container. Everytime I create a new container, new users.xml and authorizations.xml should be created. But I am still getting the grayed out buttons even when I am logging in for the first time on a new container.

Can anyone suggest me What could be the problem and how to fix this?

Under the Right top corner -> policies -> view User interface, I have the user visible. Below is the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should get /conf folder outside of the container, not just because of your problem, but also because container creates flow.gz.xml each time from scratch which overrides your flow definitions so changes are gone

copy /conf from container into your home :

```
sudo docker cp nifi-ssl:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf /home/azureuser/docker_nifi/conf
```

add your docker file a -v (persistent volume) and create container again :

```
-v /home/azureuser/docker_nifi/conf:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf
```

now all of your configuration and flow definitions are persisted , change and restart container.

as for your problem , try to give user interface access to all users.
right top menu -> Policies -> view the user interface

[here](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDF3/HDF-3.3.0/nifi-authorization/content/access_policies.html) is a good access policy documentation

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will do it. 
as to my problem, my user is already in the policy list for view user Interface, its name CN=sys_admin, OU=NIFI is visible under Policies -> view user interface, but still, I am getting greyed out buttons. I will edit my question above and even add a screenshot of the same.

Comment: If I were you , after make /conf folder persistent I would add user and give them modify and view access grant according to this [doc](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDF3/HDF-3.4.0/nifi-authorization/hdf-nifi-authorization.pdf) . I had made my security with [this link's security section](https://bryanbende.com/development/2016/08/17/apache-nifi-1-0-0-authorization-and-multi-tenancy)